# Are the pre-compact sets in a locally convex space with the weak topology exactly the bounded sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The Wikipedia article on [totally bounded space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space) claims that

> "In a locally convex space endowed with the weak topology the precompact sets are exactly the bounded sets."

The claim is repeated on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology_%28polar_topology%29) as well.

I'm a little confused by this statement.  For example, if $X$ is a non-reflexive normed vector space, then its weak topology is locally convex.  The unit sphere of $X$ is bounded, but its weak closure is the closed unit ball, which is not compact in this case.

Am I missing something?  (It's very late where I am.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you quote is correct. First, the uniform boundedness principle implies that in every normed space the weakly bounded sets and the norm bounded sets are the same, so there is no ambiguity as to what bounded could mean. Second, it is not difficult to show that every bounded ultranet is weakly Cauchy.

The issue is that pre-compactness of $U$ refers to compactness of the *completion* of $U$, which is usually distinct from the *closure*. If the normed space happens to be reflexive then the weak completion of a *bounded* set is its weak closure.

Also, a normed space is weakly complete if and only if it is finite dimensional: if $X$ is not finite-dimensional there is a discontinuous linear functional on $X^\ast$ and using this one can construct a weak Cauchy net in $X$ which does not converge.

Chapter 2 of Megginson's book is a readable source for all these facts.

Comment: I thought the definition of "pre-compact" is "has compact closure."  You're saying that there's an inequivalent definition (viz "has compact completion") in common use?  Sigh.

Comment: @JesseQualPrep: The Wikipedia page on totally bounded spaces has a few remarks on this issue. Pre-compact can either mean "totally bounded" or "relatively compact" and both usages are common. In the context of uniform spaces, the meaning "has compact completion" is probably seen more often. As wehausen argues this is the intended meaning here. When interpreting pre-compact as "has compact closure", then you are absolutely right.